# How to extract numbers in a filename from matlab?

Tags: matlab, parsing, numbers, filenames, letters

I have to read out numbers and possibly some letters from large set of file names in a directory. The file names have a format as "aXXXX_bXX_XX_S.ext" where 'X' could be any number and 's' could be any letter or a string. How do I extract those numbers and string as separate cell array?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should show us what you already tried. For now, take a look at [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) or [`strtok`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html). Good luck!

Comment: You want a [regular expression](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html?refresh=true). I suggest checking out the documentation and playing around on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to figure out the correct pattern.

Answer (score 0):

First you can read all the files inside your directory. Assuming the location of your folder is stored in the string `path`, use:

```
 a=dir(mypath);
```

Now you have a structure `a`. File names are stored in `a.name`. Now you can work with it. Here is a very rough code. You loop over all the files, check if the first letter is `a` (there could be some hidden files, you don't need them). Then you extract the data you need from the eligible files.

```
 n=0;
 for i=1:numel(a)
     if a(i).name(1)=='a'
         n=n+1; 
         numbers{n}=strcat(a(i).name(2:5),a(i).name(8:9),a(i).name(11:12));
         letters{n}=a(i).name(13:find(a(i).name=='.')-1);

     end
 end
```